# bootstrap carousel autoplay with JS is giving a trouble

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000
        });
```

this code is working but this one doesnt works

```
$('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000
        });
```

but the 1st code is making a slightly jumping when it transit from last slide to 1st.( **if u look at carousel indicator(the dots) u will see**)
Why is it happening? Plz help me
link[enter link description here](http://flypilot.in/projects/carouselplzwork/)

Comment: I your code your interval is 1200 and the jumping might be because of your visual perception.Just keep it to 5000 and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top margin for prev and next (standard prev/next buttons?) is causing that problem because it affects the "next" status of the slider items.

```
#main-slider .prev,
#main-slider .next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: #c52d2f;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  /* margin-top: -25px; */
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide a space between id and class with jquery

```
$('#main-slider .carousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000
        });
```